# Loading blog posts in Nativescript (-vue)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, drupal, nativescript

I have to make a "news" app where I load some blog post content to show in the app, much like the IGN Gaming app or any news app...

How do I go about loading the content from something like Drupal? I know how to use the API and load the content, but how do I go about building the full blog post from Drupal Content?

Do I just load the full HTML post and show it in a Webview? Or do split the content up in pieces and use nativescript components to show different pieces?

How would one go about building this? I've tried the webview and I don't really like it. It seems that on IOS I have to explicitly set a height to see the content so for blog posts this would not be ideal.

How would they have built the IGN app for full article posts? I already found how to load the content from Drupal and show them in teasers but that's just "title, image and summary" I can put that in a Component. But I can't find any hints on how to this for a full post with titles, paragraphs, images, galleries, ...

Comment: The question is too broad. Please ask what is the exact implementation issue you are facing.

Comment: As already mentioned this question is too broad. I would say, solve one problem at a time, do not mix everything. If you succeed and happy with WebView and just setting explicit height is the problem, the height can be auto adjusted with simple code - [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=1v0jG9&v=1) (It's in Angular, works for Vue too just replace Angular specific syntaxes to Vue).